java.lang.ClassCastException using restTemplate
This is my service code where I am calling "http://localhost:3232/survey" and it will return List of Employees. Method getListEmployee is working fine but when I call method findEmpById it shows me the error
Service class
@Service
public class EmployeeService {

    public List<Employee> getListEmployee() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        List<Employee> data = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:3232/survey", List.class);
        return data;
    }

    public Employee findEmpById(String id) {
        try {
         List<Employee>data=getListEmployee();
                 for(Employee e1:data){
                     System.out.println(e1.getFirstName());
                 }
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}


I am getting error in the console when I call method **findEmpById**

    java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class com.employeeService.dto.Employee (java.util.LinkedHashMap is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.employeeService.dto.Employee is in unnamed module of loader 'app')

Employee class
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Employee {

    private String EmployeeID;
    private String FirstName;
    private String LastName;
    private String Gender;
    private Integer age;
    private String BusinessTravel;
    private String Department;
    private Integer DistanceFromHome_km;
    private String State;
    private String Ethnicity;
    private String Education;
    private String EducationField;
    private String JobRole;
    private String MaritalStatus;
    private Integer Salary;
    private Integer StockOptionLevel;
    private String OverTime;
    private Date HireDate;
    private String Attrition;
    private Integer YearsAtCompany;
    private Integer YearsInMostRecentRole;
    private Integer YearsSinceLastPromotion;
    private Integer YearsWithCurrManager;
    private String id;
}


you should use a different RestTemplate method, such as exchange, in this way:
ResponseEntity<List<Employee>> entity = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:3232/survey", HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Employee>>() {});
List<String> data = entity.getBody();

In this way, you can tell how to map the collection of items that have to be deserialized in the response.

It is working but I need to use @JsonProperty in every field in EmployeeDTO. And if I use it I am getting the data but duplicate keys are present with change normal case key and camelcase key

You are not using the java bean standard, that says that every class attribuite name have to start with a lower case. Why you need the upper cases? If it's because of jaon mapping, you should use the lower case first letter for the atteibutes, then annotate them with @JsonProperty for the alias used in JSON. This approach should also be correctly manager by lombok.
